# Y Axis will not display

Tags: d3.js

My code is below.  Data is coming through fine. The X axis displays fine, No matter what I do the Y axis will not.  I tried adjusting margins, even have a working example using different data.  So I suspect it's my data for Y which runs from 1 to 7 over 20 values. Appreciate any insight into my problem.  Thanks

This is the data:

```
Data:
let massdata = {
Years: [1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017], 
USAttacks: [2,5,1,1,1,3,3,2,3,4,3,4,2,3,7,3,3,4,4,4]
}
```

sample of the d3 logic with axis definition see below

```
  function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
     return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  }

  let years = massdata.Years.map(y => y + "-1-1");
  let dates = years.map(d => fmtDate(d));

  let data = {
    x: dates,
    y: massdata.USAttacks
  };

  let y_max = Math.max.apply(Math, data.y);
  let y_min = Math.min.apply(Math, data.y);
  let y_labels = data.y.filter(onlyUnique);
  let x_max = dates[dates.length - 1];
  let x_min = dates[0];

  let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([x_min, x_max])
    .range([0, width]);

  let yScale = d3.scaleLog()
    .domain([y_min, y_max])
    .range([height, 0]);

  let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1));
  let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

  let valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d.y);
    })
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

  let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
  svg.append("G")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
}
```

The code snippet shows what is happening below

```js
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

let massdata = {
  Years: [1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008,
  2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
  USAttacks: [2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
}

let margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let fmtDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

let years = massdata.Years.map(y => y + "-1-1");
let dates = years.map(d => fmtDate(d));

let data = {
  x: dates,
  y: massdata.USAttacks
};

let y_max = Math.max.apply(Math, data.y);
let y_min = Math.min.apply(Math, data.y);
let y_labels = data.y.filter(onlyUnique);
let x_max = dates[dates.length - 1];
let x_min = dates[0];

let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([x_min, x_max])
  .range([0, width]);

let yScale = d3.scaleLog()
  .domain([y_min, y_max])
  .range([height, 0]);

let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1));
let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

let valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  })
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline(data));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
svg.append("G")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
body {
  font: 18px Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ffab00;
  stroke-width: 3;
}

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE** In the console I see this message which is preventing the Y axis from showing.  The question is how to fix it.

```
Error: <g> attribute transform: Trailing garbage, "translate(0,NaN)".
(anonymous function)    d3.v5.min.js:2
each                    d3.v5.min.js:2
attr                    d3.v5.min.js:2
l                       d3.v5.min.js:2
call                    d3.v5.min.js:2
(anonymous function)    script2.js:72
```

**UPDATE2** Getting rid of yaxis tickvalues gets rid of the error above, still will not show the y axis.

Comment: Reduce the code to smaller footprint showing only the logic that has the error

Comment: For the yScale I have tried .scaleLog and .scaleLinear both return the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the y-axis showing, you should change:

```
svg.append("G")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

to

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

i.e. it's just a typo where you are trying to append a capital `G` element, rather than a lower case `g` element.

Comment: Thanks can't believe I missed that.